Allow ssh-rsa with OpenSSH 8.7
I'm using a linux box Amazon Linux release 2023.5.20240819 (Amazon Linux) with installed  OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 and an sftp server configured.
I'm facing this problem with a customer who is trying to connect to my SFTP server, I'm pretty sure they are using an old ssh client, probably from an IBM mainframe but it's just a guess.
They use a rsa 4096 sha1 key, so I add in my sshd config this to enable them (I know I add too many, I'll remove the unnecessary once everything is ok):

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
+ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
HostKeyAlgorithms
+ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
+ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

Testing locally with customer pairs of key works fine. But once they try to connect I got this error about key exchange, and this point me to say that it is a client issue, too old most likely.

debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match) [preauth]
Unable to negotiate with "IP" port 62364: no matching host key type
found. Their offer:
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]

So I decide to add those kex algo in my sshd configuration, I also did this command not sure if it can have a impact, eventually I'll roll back once everyhign works update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
I add in file configuration sshd_config this line (even if I think ssh-rsa is not a KEX algo, but I'm a newbie here):
KexAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
but when I restart the sshd it says: Unsupported KEX algorithm "ssh-rsa"
There is a way to use legacy unsupported KEX algo?
UPDATE
I update the configuration like @u1686_grawity suggested (thanks!). I was also able to get the logs from the client (client older than 10years unfortunately OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013)
So to recap this is my sshd config:
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

this is the server log:
 debug1: Forked child 14089.
 debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
 debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
 debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
 Connection from ******** port 56548 on ****** port 47221 rdomain ""
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
 debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
 debug1: SELinux support disabled [preauth]
 debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
 debug1: list_hostkey_types: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
 debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 [preauth]
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match) [preauth]
 Unable to negotiate with 194.163.64.200 port 56548: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
 debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
 debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
 debug1: do_cleanup
 debug1: Killing privsep child 14090

and this is the client logs:
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data ....
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ********.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /......
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file ....... type 1
debug1: identity file ...... type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
no hostkey alg
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer


Poss dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/1160992/how-to-allow-ssh-rsa-with-openssh-8.7-on-amazon-linux-2023 -- for Amazon Linux you apparently need to enable ssh-rsa in sshd_config and ALSO create the host-RSA-key.

@dave_thompson_085 that link point me to the right direction, I'll update the title, now is misleading and if you write a comment I'll tag it as solution, thanks!

ssh-rsa is not a key-exchange algorithm.
The two lines in your error message are not related to each other – they report two different cases of unsupported algorithm in different categories.
Diffie-Hellman (the traditional MODP variant) is the SSH key-exchange algorithm that nearly all such old systems use, and you most likely need one of:

diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 for standard 2048-bit MODP (still passable), or

diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 for standard 768-bit MODP (very weak but might show up, as AFAIK it was one of the original "mandatory to support" SSHv2 algorithms),


...in addition to the HostKeyAlgorithms and PubkeyAlgorithms that you already have (the former is about your host key, the latter is about their key).
Note that unlike X.509 certificates, a plain SSH keypair doesn't have any signatures inside – the only signatures involved are the one-time proofs sent during connection handshake. So it's not a problem with the customer's key but with their client specifically, and it means you'll also need to offer SHA1 via HostKeyAlgorithms for your hostkey as well.
In total, you might need something like this:
# Allow mildly-outdated cipher selection
Ciphers +aes128-cbc

# Allow negotiating cipher key using weak DH
# (only add group1 if you *really* need it)
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

# Offer SHA1 signatures for host pubkey
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

# Accept SHA1 signatures for client pubkey
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Don't forget that you can run multiple instances of sshd – it's possible to have a "strong" configuration on public port 22 and "weak" configuration on alternate VPN-protected port.

thanks a lot for the tips and for the final advice, very useful

SSH 'group1' is Oakley group 2 = 1024bits

That's weird but good to know it's not as weak as I thought.
